# How to access model variables in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model in which i am populating Hash value, now i want to use that hash in view and display data to user, but in view my Hash is not available.

Any help would be great.

thanks

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a controller, one way to fix this is define that Hash as a instance variable, for example @hash.
If you not, please paste some code

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as global variable i.e.($hash) in model and use it in your view.

**OR**

You can create method in model and call it from controller for e.g.

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @hash = Test.display_value
 end
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.display_value
  hash = {'one' => '1', 'two' => '2'}
  return hash
 end
end
```

after that you can easily use @hash variable in your view.